# Where is the relevance of a board such as Politics.SE being discussed?

Tags: discussion

Apologies for the simple question, but

**Where do we discuss the relevance of a proposed board?**

**Motivation:** [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) is, in my opinion, how can I say, well, I am not sure that the community has anything to gain from it, at least not in that form.

Comment: Except that Politics SE not a "proposed board", but a fully functional Q&A site that has been operating for more than four years. It has over 3,334 questions that seem reasonably well moderated against the typical hot-button "political debates" that otherwise would *not* be a great fit for a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Alright. It carried a 'beta' tag, which confused me into thinking that it was being proposed.

Comment: Fr. Yeah, I'm with you on that issue: **[Should we rename or remove the “beta” label?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257652/should-we-rename-or-remove-the-beta-label/257747#257747)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally you discuss any issues within a community on that community's meta site. In this case, that'd be http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Fr. Happy to help. Having said that, it looks like you just joined Politics.SE earlier today, so I'd caution against raising broad discussions on relevance. Folks who actually use the site might take exception to that, so I suggest spending some time observing how the community works.

Comment: I'll be as careful as possible in the wording of my question, thank you.

Comment: Posting about how a site shouldn't exist on its own Meta...Will popcorn be provided, or should we bring our own?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's a BYOP event. ;) I agree it's probably ill-advised, but if we're gonna have a discussion about the usefulness or direction of a site, having it somewhere where the actual users don't hang out sounds even worse.